# How to show multiple images overlapping in an email template?

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email, email-templates

I am trying to display multiple profile pictures in a row with text.

Here is what I am getting  :

[image]

what I am trying to get:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve something like this by using the [Faux Absolute Position](https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position) technique. Here’s an example based on your screenshot:

```
<div style="font-size:0;">
    <span style="display:inline-block; max-width:96px; font-size:16px;">
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="128" style="border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%;" />
    </span>
    <span style="display:inline-block; max-width:96px; font-size:16px;">
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="128" style="border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%;" />
    </span>
    <span style="display:inline-block; max-width:96px; font-size:16px;">
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="128" style="border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%;" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Here are [screenshots on Email on Acid](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/7EaTBb55lmfSPe3x22NtF5kdybaWDtPoIZrmY2BNrO73j/list). This will work in most email clients (from Apple Mail, Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook.com), with a few quirks happening on less popular clients (like GMX, Comcast). In the Outlooks (2007-2019) on Windows, the images will appear as square next to each others. If we want to improve this, we can use VML to the rescue. Here's what it looks like:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<v:group style="width:320px; height:128px;" coordorigin="0 0" coordsize="320 128">
    <v:oval style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:96pt; height:96pt; z-index:1;" stroked="true" strokeweight="3pt" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
        <v:fill src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg" type="frame" size="96pt,96pt" />
    </v:oval>
    <v:oval style="position:absolute; left:72pt; top:0; width:96pt; height:96pt; z-index:1;" stroked="true" strokeweight="3pt" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
        <v:fill src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg" type="frame" size="96pt,96pt" />
    </v:oval>
    <v:oval style="position:absolute; left:144pt; top:0; width:96pt; height:96pt; z-index:1;" stroked="true" strokeweight="3pt" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
        <v:fill src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg" type="frame" size="96pt,96pt" />
    </v:oval>
</v:group>
<![endif]-->
```

Here's the overall code mixing the two solutions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>How to show multiple images overlapping in an email template?</title>
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562869/how-to-show-multiple-images-overlapping-in-an-email-template -->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:group style="width:320px; height:128px;" coordorigin="0 0" coordsize="320 128">
        <v:oval style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:96pt; height:96pt; z-index:1;" stroked="true" strokeweight="3pt" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
            <v:fill src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg" type="frame" size="96pt,96pt" />
        </v:oval>
        <v:oval style="position:absolute; left:72pt; top:0; width:96pt; height:96pt; z-index:1;" stroked="true" strokeweight="3pt" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
            <v:fill src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg" type="frame" size="96pt,96pt" />
        </v:oval>
        <v:oval style="position:absolute; left:144pt; top:0; width:96pt; height:96pt; z-index:1;" stroked="true" strokeweight="3pt" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
            <v:fill src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg" type="frame" size="96pt,96pt" />
        </v:oval>
    </v:group>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <div style="font-size:0;">
        <span style="display:inline-block; max-width:96px; font-size:16px;">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="128" style="border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%;" />
        </span>
        <span style="display:inline-block; max-width:96px; font-size:16px;">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="128" style="border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%;" />
        </span>
        <span style="display:inline-block; max-width:96px; font-size:16px;">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="128" style="border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%;" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use margins for this.

```css
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 64px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  background: transparent;
}

.imgStack {
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.imgStackText {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgStack">
<img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-png-1.png"/>
<img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-icon-png-1.png"/>
<span class="imgStackText"><strong>Male</strong> and <strong>Female</strong> are in the copy of this Email.</span>
</div>
```

**Edit**:
Try `max-width` on `td`

```css
img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 64px;
  background: transparent;
}

.smallerCell {
  max-width: 32px;
}

.imgStackText {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #035;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="smallerCell"><img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-png-1.png"/></td>
    <td class="smallerCell"><img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-icon-png-1.png"/></td>
    <td><img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-icon-png-1.png"/></td>
    <td class="imgStackText"><strong>Male</strong> and <strong>Female</strong> are in the copy of this Email.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Inline CSS, as suggested by Nathan**

```html
<div style="padding-left:32px;" >
  <img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-png-1.png" style="width:64px;height:64px;border-width:4px;border-style:solid;border-color:white;border-radius:64px;margin-left:-32px;background-color:transparent;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;" />
  <img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/avatar-icon-png-1.png" style="width:64px;height:64px;border-width:4px;border-style:solid;border-color:white;border-radius:64px;margin-left:-32px;background-color:transparent;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;" />
  <span style="font-family:Helvetica;position:relative;bottom:28px;" ><strong>Male</strong> and <strong>Female</strong> are in the copy of this Email.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: gmail is not recognising margin-left .. dont know why ?

Comment: that's weird. Try `margin: 0 0 0 -32px`

Comment: already tried no working .. strange thing is that sendgrid is showing correct preview but when mail lands in inbox margin property is not applied

Comment: Try the other code I added. It seems in Gmail only HTML Tables work.

Comment: You need to inline the code; some Gmails strip embedded CSS. Use https://inliner.cm/

Comment: the best practice in Email template is to avoid using Margin, it will strip that property, the worst case is that overlapping part you have to use an image instead. Testing on Outlook and many other mail clients and you will need that solution

Comment: Gmail doesn't support negative margins. https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-margin/